# How to simultaneously read and write two way between client-server in C# TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

In this simple code, a TCP client and a TCP server are created. My goal is to read and write from each other **simultaneously in both the client and the server**. You would notice that both the client and the server have two blocks, one to read and the other one to write. If I comment out opposite blocks in each, all is fine. For example, if the server only sends data and the client only receives data, all is good. All is working fine the other way around, if the client only sends data and the server only receives data - no issue. However, if I try to send and receive from both client and server simultaneously, then it does not work, the screens are blank, with no error messages. TCP is not my area, so any help is appreciated. What is wrong or missing in this code?

**SERVER**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServerTCP
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12346);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server Started");
        while (true)
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("The client is connected");
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ServerTask, client);
        }
    }

    static void ServerTask(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var tcpClient = (TcpClient)o)
            {
                using (var stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    //sending data
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        int j = 0;
                        while (j < 100)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss") );
                            writer.Flush();
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            j++;
                        }

                    }

                    //receive data
                    /*using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        string dateTimeString = "";
                        while ((dateTimeString = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Date & Time from Client = {dateTimeString}"); i++;

                            if (i >= 10)
                            {
                                tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
                                tcpClient.Close();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }*/

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
        }

    }
  }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClientTCP
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("localhost", 12346);

        using (var stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            //send data
            /*using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                int j = 0;
                while (j < 10)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss"));
                    writer.Flush();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    j++;
                }

            }*/


            // receive data
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                int i = 0;
                string dateTimeString = "";
                while ((dateTimeString = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Date & Time from Server = {dateTimeString}");
                    i++;

                    if (i >= 10)
                    {
                        client.GetStream().Close();
                        client.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, there is nothing special that you need to do - it should just work. Could it have something to do with the fact that you explicitly close the connection after 10 reads?

Comment: If both sides try to send a lot of data before either side attempts to read any data, you're probably filling up your buffers. Move the receive code into a separate thread (to demonstrate this idea, but then ideally switch to async code that doesn't block threads whilst waiting for the other side to act)

Comment: I don't think 10 reads are causing the problem here, I extended the loop to100 to check and no difference

Comment: Might be, but I am just trying to send/receive a tiny datetime string every minute. To verify the data volume is not an issue, I extended that interval to 10 seconds. The problem is still there. I guess I should try switching to multiple threads or async communication.